# Colocar Data no App.Config

Tags: vb.net, configuração

Tenho uma aplicação que corre como um serviço e necessitava de configurar no app.config algumas variáveis, nomeadamente datas, para que quando for necessário fazer alteração ao critério de pesquisa (nos casos em que pode ocorrer alguma falha) não ser necessário executar em debug a aplicação.

O que pretendo é algo como:

```
<add key="Data" value="DateTime.Now" />
```

Comment: A classe ConfigurationManager e' um bom ponto de partida. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Actualizei a pergunta com o que pretendo. Neste caso, essa informação não será muito útil, até porque isso já conheço. Obrigado pela dica, mas neste caso não será o que necessito

Comment: Você quer fazer parse do valor?

Comment: Encontrei a resposta que pretendia.
Foi respondida aqui: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/21778933/3206532][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21778933/3206532

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta foi a resposta que me ajudou, [proveniente do Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21778933/9835), traduzida para o português:

Se pretender definir o valor por defeito para  `DateTime.Now`, ou permitir que seja um outro valor, provavelmente pretenderá código semelhante a este:

```
Dim magicDate = If(Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("OverrideMagicDate")),
          Date.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("OverrideMagicDate")),
          Date.Now)
```

No ficheiro `app.settings`, deixe o valor de `OverrideMagicDate` vazio se quiser que ele receba `DateTime.Now` ou insira a data que pretender:

```
<add key="OverrideMagicDate" value="" /><!-- DateTime.Now -->
```

ou:

```
<add key="OverrideMagicDate" value="2012-01-13" /><!-- 13/01/2012 -->
```

Pode ser necessário trocar [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) por [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) se pretender ter maior controlo sobre os formatos de data.

Comment: Claro que há uma boa solução para esse problema em português. Olha ela aí!